# como obtener total de días trabajados en sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gracias por tu apoyo Patricio, te comento que he generado la función, la modifique de acuerdo a las variables que tengo para poder lograr el resultado lo cual logro obtener.

Agregue a la función:

- -@NumOperador

  para mostrar el numero de Operador

Retire

- -Fecha inicia,
  -Dias laborales
  -Descansos,

pero los declare más abajo para que tomaran el valor que tiene en la tabla sin necesidad de colocarlos manualmente, he realizado pruebas colocando el numero de operador la fecha desde y fecha hasta y me da el dato que necesito Total de dias Trabajados y Descansados. Te comparto el código:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(
        @numoperador int, 
        @FechaDesde DATETIME, 
        @FechaHasta DATETIME 
) RETURNS @CantidadaDiasPeriodo TABLE(
        NumOperador             INT,
        Laborables              INT,
        Descanso                INT 
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @I INT,@Start INT,@TotalDiasLaborables INT,@TotalDiasDescanso INT,@FlagLaborable INT

DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( Fecha DATETIME, Dia INT, FlagLaborable INT )
declare @FechaInicio datetime, @DiasLaborables INT, @DiasDescanso INT
    select @FechaInicio=CC.Jornada_Ini, @DiasLaborables=J.DiasLabores, @DiasDescanso= J.DiasDescanso
    from CopCalendario CC
    join trkOperadores O on CC.NumOperador= O.NumOperador
    join trkJornada J on O.cveJornada= J.cveJornada
    where (CC.NumOperador= @numoperador or @numoperador=0)

    SELECT  @Start = DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaDesde) / (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) - 1 
    SELECT  @I = 1
    WHILE   @I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaHasta) + 1
    BEGIN

        SELECT @FlagLaborable   = CASE  WHEN (@Start + (@I-1)) % (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) BETWEEN 1 AND @DiasLaborables  THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END

        INSERT INTO @Temp(Dia, Fecha,FlagLaborable)
        SELECT  @I, DATEADD(DAY, @I - 1, @FechaInicio), 
            @FlagLaborable

        SELECT @I = @I + 1
    END
    SELECT  @TotalDiasLaborables = ISNULL(SUM(FlagLaborable),0),
        @TotalDiasDescanso = ISNULL(SUM(ABS(FlagLaborable-1)),0)
        FROM @Temp
        WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta

    INSERT INTO @CantidadaDiasPeriodo(NumOperador, Laborables, Descanso)
        VALUES (@NumOperador, @TotalDiasLaborables, @TotalDiasDescanso)
            RETURN
END
```

Prueba

```
select * from dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(451073,'20170515', '20170531')
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado de la Prueba]

Ahora quiero dar el valor a numero de Operador de 0 para que me muestre todos los operadores con sus días descansados y trabajados, como lo puedo lograr? si ahorita realice una prueba pero me regresa 1 solo registro,

Prueba

```
select * from dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(0,'20170515', '20170531')
```

[image: Resultado segunda prueba]

**18 Mayo, Actual Código**
Gracias por seguir apoyándome Patricio, realmente no he utilizando las funciones y es por esto que se me dificultan un poco, estaba revisando en internet y lo que me comentas yo tengo un:
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DiasLaborablesDescansos](
debo de quitar el Alter y colocar el Drop?

Tengo el código de la siguiente manera:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DiasLaborablesDescansos](
        @Numoperador INT,
        @FechaDesde     DATETIME, 
        @FechaHasta     DATETIME, 
        --@FechaInicio    DATETIME, 
        --@DiasLaborables INT, 
        --@DiasDescanso   INT,
    @TipoDia    CHAR(1) = 'L'
) RETURNS INT

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I                   INT
    DECLARE @Start               INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasLaborables INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasDescanso   INT
    DECLARE @FlagLaborable       INT

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( 
        Fecha         DATETIME, 
        Dia           INT,
        FlagLaborable INT
    )
    declare @FechaInicio datetime, @DiasLaborables INT, @DiasDescanso INT
SELECT O.NumOperador, 
       dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(@Numoperador,@FechaDesde, @FechaHasta, 'L') AS 'DiasLaborables',
       dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(@Numoperador,@FechaDesde, @FechaHasta, 'D') AS 'DiasDescanso'
       from CopCalendario CC
       join trkOperadores O on CC.NumOperador= O.NumOperador
       join trkJornada J on O.cveJornada= J.cveJornada
       where (CC.NumOperador= @numoperador or @numoperador=0)

    SELECT  @Start = DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaDesde) / (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) - 1 
    SELECT  @I = 1
    WHILE   @I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaHasta) + 1
    BEGIN

        SELECT @FlagLaborable   = CASE  WHEN (@Start + (@I-1)) % (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) BETWEEN 1 AND @DiasLaborables  THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END

        INSERT INTO @Temp(Dia, Fecha,FlagLaborable)
        SELECT  @I, DATEADD(DAY, @I - 1, @FechaInicio), 
            @FlagLaborable

        SELECT @I = @I + 1
    END

    SELECT  @TotalDiasLaborables = ISNULL(SUM(FlagLaborable),0),
        @TotalDiasDescanso = ISNULL(SUM(ABS(FlagLaborable-1)),0)
        FROM @Temp
        WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta


    RETURN (CASE WHEN @TipoDia = 'L' THEN @TotalDiasLaborables ELSE @TotalDiasDescanso END)
END
```

O tengo que agregar algo más.

```
Drop FUNCTION [dbo].[DiasLaborablesDescansos](
```

**Código más Actual**

He dejado la función como me lo indicaste:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DiasLaborablesDescansos](
        --@NumOperador INT,
        @FechaDesde     DATETIME, 
        @FechaHasta     DATETIME,
        @FechaInicio    DATETIME, 
        @DiasLaborables INT, 
        @DiasDescanso   INT,
        @TipoDia    CHAR(1) = 'L'
) RETURNS INT

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I                   INT
    DECLARE @Start               INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasLaborables INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasDescanso   INT
    DECLARE @FlagLaborable       INT

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( 
        Fecha         DATETIME, 
        Dia           INT,
        FlagLaborable INT
    )

    SELECT  @Start = DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaDesde) / (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) - 1 
    SELECT  @I = 1
    WHILE   @I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaHasta) + 1
    BEGIN

        SELECT @FlagLaborable   = CASE  WHEN (@Start + (@I-1)) % (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) BETWEEN 1 AND @DiasLaborables  THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END

        INSERT INTO @Temp(Dia, Fecha,FlagLaborable)
        SELECT  @I, DATEADD(DAY, @I - 1, @FechaInicio), 
            @FlagLaborable

        SELECT @I = @I + 1
    END

    SELECT  @TotalDiasLaborables = ISNULL(SUM(FlagLaborable),0),
        @TotalDiasDescanso = ISNULL(SUM(ABS(FlagLaborable-1)),0)
        FROM @Temp
        WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta


    RETURN (CASE WHEN @TipoDia = 'L' THEN @TotalDiasLaborables ELSE @TotalDiasDescanso END)
END
```

Ya para mandar llamar la información Utilice el Código:

```
DECLARE @FechaDesde DATETIME
DECLARE @FechaHasta DATETIME
DECLARE @numOperador int
SET @numOperador=0
SELECT @FechaDesde = '2017-05-01'
SELECT @FechaHasta = '2017-05-31'

SELECT distinct CC.NumOperador, 
       dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(@FechaDesde, @FechaHasta, CC.Jornada_Ini, J.DiasLabores, J.DiasDescanso , 'L') AS 'DiasLaborables',
       dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(@FechaDesde, @FechaHasta, CC.Jornada_Ini, J.DiasLabores, J.DiasDescanso , 'D') AS 'DiasDescanso'
       from CopCalendario CC
       join trkOperadores O on CC.NumOperador= O.NumOperador
       join trkJornada J on O.cveJornada= J.cveJornada
       where (CC.NumOperador= @numoperador or @numoperador=0)
```

Aquí he colocado el número 0 y se logra obtener ya el número de Operador con sus días trabajados y días descansados, estaba realizando pruebas pero me esta dando los resultados incorrectos en unos me da más días trabajados y en otro mas Descansados o de forma contraria, ya se con las fechas del día 15 al 31 o del día 1 al 31 de Mayo.
[image: Resultado de la prueba]

y te Comparto información de las Jornadas que están en la tabla de trkJornada que es de ahí en donde estoy mandando los días de descanso obligatorios y de trabajo[image: Información de las Jronadas]

me estaré equivocando en algo,
con el primer operador su jornada inicial la tiene el 1 de mayo y estoy solicitando con las fechas desde 1 mayo hasta 31 de mayo y me debería de mandar 26 días de trabajo y 5 de descanso y me da 24 trabajados y 7 de descanso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tu pregunta es más de algoritmos que de SQL, de todas formas voy a intentar darte una respuesta, explicación y una prueba de concepto:

- Tu pregunta no es nada trivial, no veo que haya una forma sencilla y 
  directa de obtener los días laborables/descanso sin tener que verificar 
  cada uno de los días entre @FechaDesde y @FechaHasta para cual es cual.
- Normalmente en estos casos se suele mantener un registro de fechas de
  trabajo y descanso de cada operador ya que entonces simplemente
  deberíamos hacer unos COUNT sobre dichos registros. Imagino que el
  volumen es tan importante que eligieron este mecanismo, supongo
  además que cuando una persona tiene un régimen de jornadas de trabajo
  y descanso estas no cambian en toda la historia o si eventualmente
  cambian lo que terminan haciendo es darlo de baja como operador y
  darlo de alta nuevamente con otro régimen. La solución a continuación 
  asume esto mismo.
- Como entonces no tenemos registro sobre que días fueron laborables o
  de descanso, lo que voy a hacer es calcularlos y luego simplemente
  contarlos.
- Como no es necesario generar todos los días desde el ingreso del
  operador a la empresa, vamos a en encontrar la primer fecha laboral
  anterior o igual al inicio del período solicitado. A partir de esa 
  fecha y hasta el fin del periodo del listado vamos a verificar si cada 
  uno de los días es laborable o de descanso. Mirando el resto de la 
  división del # día / (laborables + descanso) podemos determinar que día 
  es.
- Para resolver esto hacemos una Función que va a devolver la cantidad
  de días trabajados y de descanso en función a:

  - La fecha de ingreso a la empresa
  - La cantidad de días laborables
  - La cantidad de días de descanso
  - La Fecha Desde (listado)
  - La Fecha Hasta (listado)

--

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(
        @FechaDesde     DATETIME, 
        @FechaHasta     DATETIME, 
        @FechaInicio    DATETIME, 
        @DiasLaborables INT, 
        @DiasDescanso   INT
) RETURNS @CantidadaDiasPeriodo TABLE(
        PrimerDiaLaborableCalculo   DATETIME,
        Laborables                  INT,
        Descanso                    INT 
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DiaLaborableAnteriorPeriodo DATETIME
    DECLARE @I                           INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasLaborables         INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasDescanso           INT
    DECLARE @FlagLaborable               INT

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( 
        Fecha         DATETIME, 
        Dia           INT,
        FlagLaborable INT
    )

    SELECT  @DiaLaborableAnteriorPeriodo    = DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaDesde) / (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso))*(@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso), @FechaInicio)
    SELECT  @I = 1
    WHILE   @I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @DiaLaborableAnteriorPeriodo, @FechaHasta) + 1
    BEGIN

        SELECT @FlagLaborable   = CASE  WHEN @I % (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) BETWEEN 1 AND @DiasLaborables THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END

        INSERT INTO @Temp(Dia, Fecha,FlagLaborable)
        SELECT  @I, DATEADD(DAY, @I - 1, @DiaLaborableAnteriorPeriodo), 
            @FlagLaborable

        SELECT @I = @I + 1
    END

    SELECT  @TotalDiasLaborables = ISNULL(SUM(FlagLaborable),0),
        @TotalDiasDescanso = ISNULL(SUM(ABS(FlagLaborable-1)),0)
        FROM @Temp
        WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta

    INSERT INTO @CantidadaDiasPeriodo(PrimerDiaLaborableCalculo, Laborables, Descanso)
        VALUES (@DiaLaborableAnteriorPeriodo, @TotalDiasLaborables, @TotalDiasDescanso)

    RETURN
END
```

Como prueba de concepto, tomando el caso de tu ejemplo

```
select * from dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos('20170515', '20170531', '20170501', 20, 5)
```

El retorno:

```
PrimerDiaLaborableCalculo Laborables Descanso
------------------------- ---------- --------
01/05/2017 12:00:00 a.m        12,00     5,00
```

La función como te decía es una prueba de concepto, deberías adaptarla a tus necesidades, se me ocurre que podrías devolver solo un valor en vez de un tabla como hace ahora, y retornar la cantidad de días laborables y por diferencia calcular los de descanso.

### Cambio al 16/05/2017

Una versión un poco más simplificada, no es necesario buscar el primer dia laborable anterior al período

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(
        @FechaDesde DATETIME, 
        @FechaHasta DATETIME, 
        @FechaInicio    DATETIME, 
        @DiasLaborables INT, 
        @DiasDescanso   INT
) RETURNS @CantidadaDiasPeriodo TABLE(
        Laborables              INT,
        Descanso                INT 
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I              INT
    DECLARE @Start              INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasLaborables        INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasDescanso      INT
    DECLARE @FlagLaborable          INT

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( 
        Fecha       DATETIME, 
        Dia     INT,
        FlagLaborable   INT
    )


    SELECT  @Start = DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaDesde) / (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) - 1 
    SELECT  @I = 1
    WHILE   @I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaHasta) + 1
    BEGIN

        SELECT @FlagLaborable   = CASE  WHEN (@Start + (@I-1)) % (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) BETWEEN 1 AND @DiasLaborables  THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END

        INSERT INTO @Temp(Dia, Fecha,FlagLaborable)
        SELECT  @I, DATEADD(DAY, @I - 1, @FechaInicio), 
            @FlagLaborable

        SELECT @I = @I + 1
    END

    SELECT  @TotalDiasLaborables = ISNULL(SUM(FlagLaborable),0),
        @TotalDiasDescanso = ISNULL(SUM(ABS(FlagLaborable-1)),0)
        FROM @Temp
        WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta

    INSERT INTO @CantidadaDiasPeriodo(Laborables, Descanso)
        VALUES (@TotalDiasLaborables, @TotalDiasDescanso)

    RETURN
END
```

### Cambio al 17/05/2017

Con esta variante de la función, en vez de retornar una tabla va a retornar un único valor o los días laborables o los días de descanso, esto se va a establecer por un nuevo parámetro que es tipo de día. La función quedaría así (atención hay que dropear la función vieja, no sirve hacer alter)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(
        @FechaDesde     DATETIME, 
        @FechaHasta     DATETIME, 
        @FechaInicio    DATETIME, 
        @DiasLaborables INT, 
        @DiasDescanso   INT,
    @TipoDia    CHAR(1) = 'L'
) RETURNS INT

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I                   INT
    DECLARE @Start               INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasLaborables INT
    DECLARE @TotalDiasDescanso   INT
    DECLARE @FlagLaborable       INT

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( 
        Fecha         DATETIME, 
        Dia           INT,
        FlagLaborable INT
    )


    SELECT  @Start = CASE WHEN @FechaInicio >= @FechaDesde THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaDesde) / (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) - 1 END

    SELECT  @I = 1
    WHILE   @I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaHasta) + 1
    BEGIN

        SELECT @FlagLaborable   = CASE  WHEN (@Start + (@I-1)) % (@DiasLaborables + @DiasDescanso) BETWEEN 1 AND @DiasLaborables  THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END

        INSERT INTO @Temp(Dia, Fecha,FlagLaborable)
        SELECT  @I, DATEADD(DAY, @I - 1, @FechaInicio), 
            @FlagLaborable

        SELECT @I = @I + 1
    END

    SELECT  @TotalDiasLaborables = ISNULL(SUM(FlagLaborable),0),
        @TotalDiasDescanso = ISNULL(SUM(ABS(FlagLaborable-1)),0)
        FROM @Temp
        WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta


    RETURN (CASE WHEN @TipoDia = 'L' THEN @TotalDiasLaborables ELSE @TotalDiasDescanso END)
END
```

De esta forma, es más sencillo integrarla a tu consulta. Te muestro como sería con tus datos:

```
SELECT O.NumOperador, 
       dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(@FechaDesde, @FechaHasta, CC.Jornada_Ini, J.DiasLabores, 'L') AS 'DiasLaborables',
       dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(@FechaDesde, @FechaHasta, CC.Jornada_Ini, J.DiasLabores, 'D') AS 'DiasDescanso'
       from CopCalendario CC
       join trkOperadores O on CC.NumOperador= O.NumOperador
       join trkJornada J on O.cveJornada= J.cveJornada
       where (CC.NumOperador= @numoperador or @numoperador=0)
```

## Importante

Esta forma de resolver el problema tiene sus desventajas, a nivel performance, estamos recargando la consulta por cada registro con dos llamadas a la función, que de por sí tiene un WHILE con varias instrucciones que aumentan en función del rango del período a listar. Se podría evitar los dos llamados por uno solo,  simplemente insertando tu consulta en una temporal con el dato de los días laborables y luego "updatear" por diferencia el de descanso. De cualquier forma incorporar una UDF en una consulta tiene su penalidad en performance. Si esto fuera un problema, te sugiero algo que ya te comenté, que es armar una tabla con Operador, Fecha, Es Laborable S/N?. Y diariamente, mediante un JOB ir actualizando esta tabla, la consulta luego sería mucho más directa ya que solo tendríamos que contar estos días.

## Agregado al 18/5

Para probar la nueva función, adjunto un ejemplo sencillo:

```
DECLARE @FechaDesde DATETIME
DECLARE @FechaHasta DATETIME

SELECT @FechaDesde = '20170515'
SELECT @FechaHasta = '20170531'

SELECT dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(@FechaDesde, @FechaHasta, Jornada_Ini, DiasLabores, DiasDescanso, 'L') AS 'DiasLaborables',
       dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos(@FechaDesde, @FechaHasta, Jornada_Ini, DiasLabores, DiasDescanso, 'D') AS 'DiasDescanso'
       FROM (   SELECT '20170501' AS 'Jornada_Ini',
                    20         AS 'DiasLabores',
                    5          AS 'DiasDescanso'
        UNION
        SELECT '20170501' AS 'Jornada_Ini',
                    10         AS 'DiasLabores',
                    2          AS 'DiasDescanso'
    ) F
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, darte las gracias por darle seguimiento a mi 
pregunta y más porque me has ayudado demasiado ya que es justo
lo que necesito, he cambiado los datos a ingresar coloque numero 
de operador, y deje solo fecha desde y fecha hasta que es lo que 
necesito para que funcione. modifique el contenido de mi 
pregunta a como lo tengo ya que con lo que tengo solo muestro 1 
operador lo que quiero hacer es  mostrar todos los días 
trabajados de los operadores, puedes revisarlo por favor y ver 
que puedo hacer para ver el reporte de todos. Gracias nuevamente
@Patricio Moracho

Comment: Agrego una actualización a mi respuesta respondiendo tus comentarios. También te recuerdo que en estos se estila abrir una nueva pregunta en vez de modificar la actual. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Patricio, he realizado una prueba con lo que me indicas pero me marca el siguiente error: Las sentencias select incluidas en una función no pueden devolver datos a un cliente.

Comment: La última versión que puse en mi respuesta requiere que primero hagas un DROP de la función anterior, no funciona hacer un ALTER por que cambió el tipo de retorno (antes devolvíamos una tabla y luego un único valor). En mi entorno la he probado y funciona correctamente, agrego a la respuesta una forma de probarla

Comment: Hola Patricio, nuevamente gracias por seguir apoyandome, te comento realmente no habia utilizado funciones por lo cual se me hace un tanto complicado en donde colocar el Drop.
Yo tenía;
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DiasLaborablesDescansos]( 
ahora en lugar de Alter solo sera Drop ?

He agregado a mi pregunta como tengo actualmente el código si modificar lo anterior.

Comment: un ALTER normalmente modifica una funciona, una tabla un SP, etc. En este caso queremos modificar la función pero el SQL no la va a permitir por que cambio el valor de retorno, por lo que primero vas a tener que borrar la funcion vieja y volverla a crear. Primero: `DROP FUNCTION dbo.DiasLaborablesDescansos` y luego pegas el código nuevo de la  función que tiene  CREATE en vez de ALTER.

Comment: He eliminado la función y la he vuelto a crear, he realizado una prueba, ya me muestra todos los números de operador pero los días Laborables y de descanso me los da en ceros

Comment: Lo mas probable es que haya algún error en la forma que pasas los parámetros, trata de aislar un caso que funcione mal y pega los datos en el último ejemplo que puse y verificalo. Fijate que Fecha/hasta sean consistentes.

Comment: Ya agregue a mi consulta los parámetros ya que había quitados algunos y por esto no me mostraba las días trabajados y descansados, ahora los puedo ver pero me los da incorrectos, agregue el contenido de como tengo y los resultados que obtengo puede ser que me este faltando algo ?

Comment: Es cierto, por que no estaba considerando los casos dónde la FechaDesde del listado es inferior a la Fecha de inicio del operador. Ahí edite la última versión de la función con este cambio.

Comment: ahí ya me los corrigió, solo me quedo detalle con uno que es el numero de Operador 451138 ya que tiene Jornada de 7x0 7 días trabaja y no descansa  osea que continua siempre trabajando, me debería de quedar los 15 días trabajando y 0 descansando

Comment: La función no considera los casos en que cualquiera de los dos días es 0, tampoco si los dos son 0. Agrega una verificación al principio de la función para contemplar estos 3 casos. Si descanso es 0 todos los días desde/hasta son laborables, al revés son descanso y laborables 0 y si ambos son 0 siempre debiéramos devolver 0 en laborable y descanso.

Comment: Patricio, Muchísimas gracias por todo tu ayuda y paciencia para ayudarme a dar con el resultado, es justo lo que necesitaba, que tengas un excelente día. Saludos @Patricio